# I have removed some pages from the Google index using webmaster tools but it still shows up in the search results

Tags: google-search-console

I have removed some pages from the Google index using webmaster tools but it still shows up in the search results. So you have any idea what would be the problem? You can see the screenshots below
[image: Removal request]

[image: Search Results]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google's removal guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/59819?hl=en):

> URL removal requests expire after 90 days, after which the content may appear in our search results again. To remove a page or image from the index completely, you must do one of the following:
>
> Make sure the content is no longer live on the web. Requests for the page must return an
>
> - HTTP 404 (not found) or 410 status code.
> - Block the content using a robots.txt file.
> - Block the content using a meta noindex tag.

None of these are true for this page.

Your *robots.txt* file says:

```
User-agent: *
Crawl-delay: 20
Allow: /
```

The page returns a 200 status:

```
curl -s http://www.medikalyasam.com/Sabun,LA_1332-2.html‎ --head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

There is no robots meta tag or HTTP header in the page. (verified with `curl -s -D - http://www.medikalyasam.com/Sabun,LA_1332-2.html‎ | grep -i robot`)

You appear to have some JavaScript somewhere such that when a user visits the page with JavaScript enabled, they get sent to `http://www.medikalyasam.com/index.php?do=static/error`.    I would not advise trying to handle error conditions with JavaScript.  Rather your server should be configured to respond with an appropriate error status (such as `404 Not Found`) rather than a `200 OK` status.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe it says to completely remove it (Even after 90 days) you must give a 404 response. And i don`t have the access neither to the codes nor to robots.txt. Isn`t that possible to remove a page which is still live ? That is what i understand reading the removal doc. What do you say ?

Comment: I would not rely on that tool to remove live URLs.  At best the removal will only be good for 90 days and you would have to remove it again. It is much better to take control of your server.

Comment: I agree totally, but this i a commercial site which i have really little control of. So will the links be removed or not ? i am really confused.